# Dagger 2 field injection is not working in Android

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

The issue is that I try to use field injection with Dagger 2, but at runtime field, that should be injected, always is `null`. Also I try to use MVVM pattern. Here is my code:

ProfileActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "ProfileActivity: onStart: ");

    final ProfileViewModel profileViewModel 
         = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
    profileViewModel.init();
    profileViewModel.getUser().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ProfileActivity: onStart: " + user.toString());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ProfileActivity: onStart: user == null");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

ProfileViewModel.java:

```
public class ProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<User> user;

    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public ProfileViewModel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ProfileViewModel: Constructor: ");
    }

    public void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ProfileViewModel: init: ");
        user = userRepository.getUser();
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ProfileViewModel: getUser: ");
        return user;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java:

```
@Singleton
public class UserRepository {
    private LiveData<User> user;

    @Inject
    public UserRepository() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UserRepository: Constructor: ");
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UserRepository: getUser: ");
        if (user != null) {
            return user;
        } else {
            // There should be userDao.load() call,
            // but it had been omitted for brevity.
            MutableLiveData<User> user = new MutableLiveData<>();
            user.setValue(DB.getUser());
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

MyApplication.java:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DaggerMyApplicationComponent.create().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

MyApplicationModule.java:

```
@Module
public abstract class MyApplicationModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ProfileActivity contributeActivityInjector();
}
```

MyApplicationComponent.java:

```
@Component(modules = { AndroidInjectionModule.class, MyApplicationModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface MyApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
    void inject(ProfileActivity profileActivity);
}
```

At runtime I can see the next logs:

```
ProfileActivity: onStart:
ProfileViewModel: Constructor:
ProfileViewModel: init:
```

And the app crashes on `user = userRepository.getUser();` inside `ProfileViewModel`'s `init()` method.

It means that `UserRepository` had not been injected. Also it is indicated by missing `UserRepository: Constructor:` log.

Where is my mistake? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is to use `ViewModel Factory` to pass injected `UserRepository` into your `ViewModels` constructor, initialize it and then you will be able to use it. You cannot use field or parameter injections in `ViewModels`.

I would suggest you to follow this article: [Add the new ViewModel to your MVVM](https://medium.com/@dpreussler/add-the-new-viewmodel-to-your-mvvm-36bfea86b159)

It provides enough sufficient information to begin using Dagger 2 with Architecture Components.

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day! The issue is resolved.